# How to create a view with an extra column based on existing data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

What I am trying to achieve is to basically create a view from an existing table, but I need to add an extra column which will act as the data category.

I have already achieved this in excel, but with all the extra formulas and data my files are too big. I would like to create the categories in SQL if possible.

The data is auto-updated and contains web traffic data. The extra column needs to define the 'Channel'. For example;

There are currently three columns that are used to specify which channel the traffic is coming from - source, medium and campaign. I need to create a formula based on the data in each of these columns. For example, if campaign contains "xx-xx" then it's Channel value will be 'Example Channel'. But if Source = 'example-source' AND Medium = 'example-medium' then its Channel will be 'Example Channel2'

There are 8 channels in total, and for me to do this in excel I needed one column of 8 nested IF statements, plus an extra column with three nested IF statements to get what I wanted. I needed the second column to basically subtract some data from the channels created in the first channel column.

I hope I am making sense here, but please forgive me if I am not being clear enough. It makes sense in my mind, but it might not for someone else.

I assume I need to create a view which includes some kind of IF or CASE statement, but I am very new to SQL, so any help will be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this using the `case` statement in Excel:

```
select (case when campaign like '%xx-xx%' then 'Example Channel'
             when source = 'example-source' and medium = 'example-medium'
             then 'Example Channel2'
             . . .
        end) as channel
```

Comment: That works perfectly :-). It's so easy when you know how. hehe. Many thanks for your help